# Rxjava2 and rertrofit error handling not working

Tags: error-handling, retrofit, rx-java2

I am using retrofit 2 and rxjava2 in my project and I am struggling in handling the error .

```
        private Observable<Segment> executeUploadVideoUseCase(Segment segment) {
        LogDnaLogger.info("Segment upload: " + segment.toString());

        return mUploadVideoUseCase.execute().flatMap(voidResponse -> {
            LogDnaLogger.info("Segment upload success : " + segment.toString());
            return Observable.just(segment);
        });

    }

mUploadVideoUseCase.execute() is returning 
Observable<Response<Void>>.
```

I am coming in Segment upload success log even there is 400 bad request exception.

How can I handle 400 bad request here and pass that exception to calling function?

Answer (score 0):

when you declare your interface as `Observable<Response<T>>` success and HTTP errors are delivered in `onNext` and `onError` is called only in case of IO exception in case of network errors.

You can use `Response.isSuccess()` to check if it's a successful call or HTTP error.

The other alternative declarations from the [javadoc](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/884f37e0663e516937759a0a7d23af705ecfaaec/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.java#L45):

There are three configurations supported for the `Observable`, `Flowable`,
  `Single`, `Completable` and `Maybe` type parameter:

- Direct body (e.g., `Observable<User>`) calls `onNext` with the deserialized body
  for 2XX responses and calls `onError` with `HttpException` for non-2XX responses and `IOException` for network errors.
- Response wrapped body (e.g., `Observable<Response<User>>`) calls `onNext`
  with a `Response` object for all HTTP responses and calls `onError` with
  `IOException` for network errors
- Result wrapped body (e.g., `Observable<Result<User>>`) calls `onNext` with a
  `Result` object for all HTTP responses and errors.